# WPF application builds and starts but hangs inside the Main() method

Tags: wpf, compilation, launch

I have a WPF application. When i compile and run with "Step into new Instance", the observations are as follows:

1. The Main() method is hit
2. I can not jump into "calling the new instance of the App" with F11. That line is skipped and the next one is hit.
3. The Run() method is hit. It keeps hanging there for around 30 seconds, then the output windows says: Thread'... has exited with code 0 (0x0).

the Main method is as follows:

```
    public static void Main(){
             App app = new App();
             app.Run();
    }
```

I would very much appreciate some advise on this one.
Thanks in advance :)

Forgot to mention, this is part of a big project with multiple windows. I just wrote the entry point of the program because that's where the error happens. It used to work well in the past. However now, for reasons i don't know, it stopped working as i described above. Thx

Comment: Euphoric already gave the correct answer imho. I want to add for your point 2. You can't step into something from which you don't have the source code. So Visual studio skips this line. If you have [setup the symbol server](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/serversetup.aspx), you could as long as microsoft finally releases the newest symbols for the current framework version.

Comment: Thanks dowhilefor and Euphoric for both your replies. However its my mistake i forgot to mention, this Main method is part of a really big project with several windows, web services and DB connections... It worked in the past, then ended up with the situation i described. After calling the Run() method, the code of the main window is not initiated.

Answer (score 2):

That is perfectly normal. `app.Run()` will end only when application is terminated. And that happens when either `app.Shutdown()` is called or main window is closed.
And you don't show any main window. So that leaves manual call to `Shutdown()`.

Comment: Thanks Euphoric for your reply.

Comment: Thanks Euphoric for your reply. The problem is that nothing executes. No window appears. I can't jump into the next lines of execution with F11. i.e i can't even see which lines execute (Probably because none executes). All what i see is app.Run() with a green arrow next to it

Comment: @PierreFares Like I said. Your code has no window to display, so nothing displaying is just normal. Use app.Run(window) to show specific window. And like I said. The code will continue after app.Run() after the app shutdowns. It is still running, albeit in the background.